# При запуске скрипта на PyQt6 qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt6

При запуске скрипта на PyQt6 из под Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS выдает ошибку:

> qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even
> though it was found. This application failed to start because no Qt
> platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may
> fix this problem.
>
> Available platform plugins are: linuxfb, wayland-egl, minimal, eglfs,
> wayland, vnc, vkkhrdisplay, minimalegl, xcb, offscreen.

Этот же скрипт под Виндой10 запускается без проблем.
Пробовал установить QT Creator, Qt Designer - не помогло.